# camunda-webapp and JAAS-authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, jaas, business-process-management, camunda

In a Wildfly 8.1.0.Final we deploy:

- our own CRM-webapp (Seam2/JSF1.2)
- camunda-webapp 7.3.0
- camunda-engine 7.3.0 as a module (shared engine)
- custom engine-plugin to enable camunda-engine to use the user/group-store of our CRM

We display camunda tasklist in an iframe inside our CRM.
This setup runs fine so far, but we have to login twice.

So we need SSO, but cannot establish AD/LDAP, like in camunda-sso-jboss example.
I thought of Wildfly's JAAS and SSO capabilities, but i'am not sure, if camunda-webapp supports JAAS-authentication.
I think the security-domain configuration in jboss-web.xml is just generated by a maven archetype and has no effect on the camunda-webapp, is that right? I changed that configuration and it had no effect at all.

Can someone give me a hint, where i should hook into camunda-webapp or if it is possible at all?

Comment: I see there is an open feature request: https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-947 . Is there already some work done that i can base my own work on?

Comment: No progress has been made in this respect I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have a first success.

I changed org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.Authentications.getFromSession to accept HttpServletRequest as parameter instead of HttpSession (called from AuthenticationFilter.doFilter). If the session contains no Authentications, i try to pull the Principle from the request and if one exists, i log em in silently (copied most from UserAuthenticationResource.doLogin).

Then i have a very simple webapp ("testA") with only one JSP and Basic Authentication. Both camunda-webapp and testA have the same security-domain configured, and the host in the undertow-subsystem has the "single-sign-on"-setting.

Now i can login into /testA, then call /camunda in another tab without further authentication.

The code has to be improved a lot. If everythink works fine, i'll post the details.

If someone thinks this is a wrong approach, please let me know ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your description! Could you please post some details how did you edit the classes? I am currently trying to do roughly the same but with Spring Security.